# correct wiring of a preamplifier and a lock-in amplifier

Tags: wiring, preamp

I've got a question regarding the correct wiring.

I'm operating a vibrating sample magnetometer. It uses two coils to detect the magnetisation via induction. The two signals are amplified and mixed together in a preamplifier. Finally, a lockin is used to detect the signal.

The preamplifier output uses uses a 6 pin socket with the following pin allocation.

```
Pin Name
1   0/P
2   0/P GND
3   GND
4   -20V
5   +20V
```

The SR830 lock-in amplifier has two BNC sockets which can be used as a differential input. Also it has the option to float or ground the BNC shield. Additionally it has a D-sub preamp connector.

```
Pin Name
1   +20V 
6   -20V
7   S GND
8   GND
```

Since everything has different connections, I was thinking of making a box with a 6 pin input connector two bnc outputs and a D Sub output.

Since I'm not an electric engineer, the ground connections confuse me and were the shields should be connected.

Comment: ...and what is the question?

Comment: It looks like you are asking about what connections you should use. Since you got this connectivity problem, we can assume that you are not using SRS compatible preamp.The "box" you're talking about is just an interface converter: from preamp's output interface to lock-in's input interface, right? I can't understand why do you you want D-sub output: if you want to power your preamp from D-sub, then D-sub from lock-in should be an input to your "box".

Comment: Is your preamp a sr570? We just run the output right into the 830 and run the preamp off of its internal battery. The BNC cables supply our grounding.

Comment: If your preamp can not be powered from batteries, float your BNC. You want only ONE ground connection between the sr830 and your preamp.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you need to supply +20V (5), -20V (4) and power ground (3) seperately.

I'd wire the preamp to the lock-in amp with a BNC lead from the lock-in amp to pin 1 and 2 on the pre-amp and check that you get the desired performance.

Have the lock-in amp working differentially if you think performance isn't good enough.

Then, if all else fails, I'd contact the supplier and ask them what they'd recommend - they are the experts.

Do this before you think about building a box for the simple reason - until you have a benchmark performance you are happy with, you cannot tell if when introducing a "neater" box will deteriorate the signal in any way.